# Matplotlib stackplot ValueError need at least one array to concatenate

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to create a stackplot using matplotlib. However, whatever I try I end up with `ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate`

Just to get started, the code I try to run is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.stackplot(x=range(4), y=[ [2,2,2,2], [1,2,3,4] ], labels=['a','b'])
```

Anyone has any ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.stackplot(range(4), [2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], labels=['a', 'b'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I would recommend keeping the array as it is, `plt.stackplot(range(4), [[2,2,2,2], [1,2,3,4]], labels=['a','b'])`. The main point is just that `x` and `y` are positional arguments, no keyword arguments.